# Could not find ffi-1.9.4 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using Nitrous.io to run this project.

It was working until I installed rvm and a new version of ruby (2.1.3).

```
~/workspace/myapp$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Could not find ffi-1.9.4 in any of the sources
```

It's probably NOT a problem with ruby. 
Though I think ffi-1.9.4 might be a new ruby dependency.

I've been investigating the issue for half an hour and found nothing on Stack Overflow.

So I was wondering if someone had the same issue before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is already known and can be found on the link below:

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/374

So you only have to (1) find where the dependency is in your project, probably in your Gemfile.lock, and (2) change its version to 1.9.5. Now you can finally (3) `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue

```
bundle update

bundle install

spring stop

rails s
```